# Amplitude and Phase spectrum of a signal

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, dft, homework

[image]

Please help me to solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the spectrum is complex conjugate symmetric around $f_s/2$ (and multiples etc.) the corresponding signal is real valued and vice versa.

This holds for your example, meaning your signal should be real-valued. Your phase spectrum is interesting, since zero phase shift in all frequencies means your spectrum is real valued as well.